# AWS workspace: not receiving email on creation of workspace

Tags: boto3, amazon-workspaces

I am using boto3 to create AWS workspaces. I am not getting any email.

```
response_workspace = client_workspace.create_workspaces(
        Workspaces=[
            {
                'DirectoryId': directory_id,
                'UserName': username,
                'BundleId': bundle_id,
                'WorkspaceProperties': {
                    'RunningMode': 'AUTO_STOP'
                }
            },
        ]
    )
```